# firebase permission_denied when running program

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a problem that I searched the web for and found really one answer and it did not work for me. I have an app where users can post images and a feed of all posted the images loads for them. One problem I keep getting the error of permission_denied in the output. I am quite confused and when I looked up an answer to this, all I got was try ref.removeAllObservers, but my code already has this. Here is my code, check it out:

```
 func fetchPosts () {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let postSnap = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        for (_,post) in postSnap {

            let posst = Post()
            if let author = post["author"] as? String, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {
                posst.author = author
                posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                posst.postID = postID
                self.posts.append(posst)
            }

                self.postTableView.reloadData()

        }


    })
ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Please let me know if you have an answer. Also here is the output:

> 2017-05-03 08:06:31.771 Postflur[21064]      [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /posts failed: permission_denied

Comment: Are you having this issue when attempting to post/get from firebase? Or just in this specific instance?

Comment: Umm I think I solved it, i needed to change myCheckLogin from viewdidload to viewwillppear because no one was logged in and it was not presenting the logout vc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to hear that you have solve it (I read it in the comment section) , but I wanted anyway to write this answer because I get a similar problem in the past. 
So by default firebase database only readable/writeable by authenticated users(if you take a look at rules inside your firebase console you will find the following):

```
  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

So to let a non authenticated user read/ write data you should change the rules to the following

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

and this was the solution for me.